# How to dispatch more than one action in mapDispatchToProps in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

There are three functions in mapDispatchToProps. I want to use any function from them in constructor of React Component but when I use `console.log(this.props)`it gives undefined how Can I use these functions in constructor to load data from firebase database?

mapDispatchToProps

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addProductRequest: (data) => {
            console.log(data)
            dispatch(AddNewProduct(data))
        },
        loadProducts: () => {
            dispatch(ViewProducts())
        },
        loadStores: () => {
            dispatch(ViewStores())
        },
    }
}
```

Constructor

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        products: [],
        stores: [],
        currentProduct: [],
        stockAvailable: [],
        productName: '',
        description: '',
        qty: 0,
        unitPrice: 0,
        storeName: '',
        selectedProduct: '',
        productNameInStock: '',
        productQtyInStock:0
    }
    console.log(this.props)

    this.props.loadProducts();
    this.props.loadStores();

    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    this.inputHandler = this.inputHandler.bind(this);
}
```

it gives an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadProducts' of undefined

Comment: instead of using `mapDispatchToProps`  why not just do it like this `this.props.dispatch(ViewProducts())`. In my opinion much more clear.

Comment: I can use it but I want to use in mapDispatchToProps, Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would use `bindActionCreators` from `redux`, f.e.:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        ...bindActionCreators({ loadProducts, loadStores }, dispatch)
    }
}
```

In that case you will be able to create action through `this.props.loadProducts()` in component.

Answer (score 0):

Now its Working , I forgot to pass props in constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
        products: [],
        stores: [],
        currentProduct: [],
        stockAvailable: [],
        productName: '',
        description: '',
        qty: 0,
        unitPrice: 0,
        storeName: '',
        selectedProduct: '',
        productNameInStock: '',
        productQtyInStock:0
    }
    console.log(props)

    props.loadProducts();
    props.loadStores();

    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    this.inputHandler = this.inputHandler.bind(this);
}
```